# PHP MYSQLi Database not updating

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I've been trying to find the problem for 3 nights. It gave me nightmares. Please help. I think my code is already perfect. Can someone please fix my code and tell me whats wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT py.idPembayaran, p.idPelajar, p.nama, b.namaBarangan, 
pb.kuantiti, b.harga, py.jumlahBayaran, py.statusPembayaran, 
py.statusPenghantaran, pb.tarikhPembelian FROM barangan b
INNER JOIN pembelian pb on pb.idBarangan = b.idBarangan
INNER JOIN pembayaran py on py.idPembelian = pb.idPembelian
INNER JOIN pelajar p on p.idPelajar = pb.idPelajar";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo '
    <form method="POST" action="purchaselist.php">

        <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="idPembayaran" value="<?php echo $idPembayaran ?>">
            <td>'.$row["idPembayaran"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["idPelajar"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["nama"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["namaBarangan"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["kuantiti"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["harga"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["jumlahBayaran"].'</td>


            <td>
                <select name="statusPembayaran">
                    <option value="In process">In process</option>
                    <option value="Successful">Successful</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
                <select name="statusPenghantaran">
                    <option value="In process">In process</option>
                    <option value="Arrived">Arrived</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>'.$row["tarikhPembelian"].'</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    ';
}
}

if (!empty($_POST["submit"])) {

$idPembayaran = $_POST["idPembayaran"];
$statusPembayaran = $_POST["statusPembayaran"];
$statusPenghantaran = $_POST["statusPenghantaran"];

$sql = "UPDATE pembayaran SET statusPembayaran ='".$statusPembayaran."', statusPenghantaran ='".$statusPenghantaran."' WHERE idPembayaran = '".$idPembayaran."'";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    echo "
        <script>
        alert('test');
        window.location.href = 'purchaselist.php';
        </script>
    ";
}
else {
    echo "Update error.";
}
}
```

Im trying to update table "pembayaran" but it is not updating.
There is only two column that i want to update which is "statusPembayaran" and "statusPenghantaran" in that table. The value is from select option.

Comment: `echo "Update error.";` that won't help you here. Use `mysqli_error($conn)` instead and enable error reporting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But thats not the problem. The `if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { ` is executed and it has no error but the database is not updating after I press the button.

Comment: what about > http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?

Comment: use `mysqli_affected_rows()` also.

Comment: I would start by echoing or loging $sql just before you run it to make sure you are passing it the values you think you should be.  Also, if you take that string and run it in a mySQL editor like myPHPadmin or Workbench you can often get more pointed error notes than your browser will give you.

Comment: Also, when you are done, you'll probably want to swap that concatenated SQL string out for a prepared statement.  The code as is is vulnerable to SQL injection.  In fact, if your input includes things like quotes or apostrophes or other mySQL syntax, you may be breaking your query with bad input

Comment: @Nosajimiki its ok im just doing it for my school project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the value for the field `idPembayaran` in the first place, you have...

```
<input type="hidden" name="idPembayaran" value="<?php echo $idPembayaran ?>">
```

at this point `$idPembayaran` isn't set, it should be `$row["idPembayaran"]` which is the value from the SELECT...

```
<input type="hidden" name="idPembayaran" value="<?php echo $row["idPembayaran"]; ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro. I can now sleep in peace. Finally someone fixed my problem!